# Why is SCCM causing MSI handle leaks?

Tags: memory-leaks, windows-installer, installshield, windows-server-2012-r2, sccm

So I have several MSI packages which we use to deploy to our production environment with an in house application. But recently we started moving to SCCM. This is when the problem started, most of the MSIs tend to have handle leaks. My observations below -

- Tried manual installation of the MSI - **works fine**
- Tired using MSIEXEC with verbose logging - **works fine**
- Same MSI being installed thru SCCM **fails** with mishandle leak errors. All these leaks tend to happen in the custom actions in *.rul files.

Note that this is **not specific to a particular MSI or particular server**, similar behavior is observed in several MSI packages and in several servers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you code the custom actions or are they supplied by InstallShield? Is there any indication in the log that the custom action has crashed (a common cause of leaks)?  Are you publishing to the user or the machine (because a per user install and a per system install are very different)?  Perhaps post the actual log extract that shows the issue.

Comment: Custom action is written by us and it works fine outside SCCM. I can't post the logs due to my company's polices, but I can answer your questions for sure. Even the verbose logs don't say anything more. The moment custom action is hit, it leaks MSI handle. The application gets published to the machine. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Usually deployments through SCCM run under the LocalSystem account, maybe that is causing the custom action to behave like this.

You can run the package with [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psexec.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on your local machine and simulate a similar execution, to see if that is the case.

[- Debugging custom actions - MSI handle leaks](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2008/02/12/debugging-custom-actions-leaked-handles/)

Comment: You are right. I was able to replicate it. But I am still wondering what would be the fix for this? Any pointers?

Comment: I've added a link in my answer, maybe that can help. It's hard to say what is the problem. You'll need to attach and debug your code.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I've already gone thru all those and posted my question here only when I couldn't find anything.